# How to implement full text search Filter on foreign key field with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, filter, full-text-search

I want to filter user on the basis of company and user first name and last name.

**Here is my code -**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Indexed
@FullTextFilterDefs({ @FullTextFilterDef(name = "UserFilterByCompanyId", impl = UserFilterFactoryByCompany.class) })
public class User implements Principal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    @Column(name = "mobile")
    private String mobile;

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Transient
    @Column(name = "project_ids")
    private List<Long> projectIds;

    @Transient
    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @Column(name = "company_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long companyId;

    public User() {

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Long> getProjectIds() {
        return projectIds;
    }

    public void setProjectIds(List<Long> projectIds) {
        this.projectIds = projectIds;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public Long getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(Long companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }
}
```

**FulltextSearch** Implementation class

```
public PageResult search(int start, int size, String content, long companyId) {
        EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HibernatePersistence")
                .createEntityManager();
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
        try {

            try {
                fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(User.class).get();
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb.keyword().onFields("firstName", "lastName", "mobile", "email")
                    .matching(content).createQuery();
            javax.persistence.Query fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, User.class);
            ((FullTextQuery) fullTextQuery).enableFullTextFilter("UserFilterByCompanyId").setParameter("companyId",
                    companyId);
            fullTextQuery.setFirstResult(start);
            fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(size);
            int count = fullTextQuery.getResultList().size();
            List<User> userResult = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
            if (userResult.size() != 0) {
                PageResult pageResults = new PageResult();
                pageResults.setData(userResult);
                pageResults.setTotalResult(count);
                return pageResults;
            } else {
                logger.error("does not found any matched record with content:-" + content);
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("No record matching with " + content);
            }

        } catch (HibernateException exception) {
            logger.error("abnormal ternination, search() of user");
            throw new HibernateException("unable to process your request");
        } finally {
            if (fullTextEntityManager != null) {
                fullTextEntityManager.close();
                logger.info("session closed successfully");
            }
            fullTextEntityManager = null;
        }
    }
```

and finally here is filter logic

```
public class UserFilterFactoryByCompany {
    private long companyId;

    public void setCompanyId(long companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    public long getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    @Key
    public FilterKey getKey() {
        StandardFilterKey key = new StandardFilterKey();
        key.addParameter(companyId);
        return key;
    }

    @Factory
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Query query = (Query) new TermQuery(new Term("company_id", companyId+"".toString()));
        return new CachingWrapperFilter(new QueryWrapperFilter((org.apache.lucene.search.Query) query));
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but I am not getting any results(means getting null in result). can anyone help me please.

Comment: Hi everyone, I got the solution of this problem. Actually I was forget to mention @Field annotation to the companyId in User model
now its working fine